# libtensorflow.so compiled with g++ 4.8 exports non c++11 symbols but external software uses c++11 from tensorflow headers

Tags: c++, linux, tensorflow, c++11, g++4.8

I am trying to compile tensorflow on a Linux machine with a g++ 4.8 compiler. I also need to use it in an external software. The problem is as follows:

when I compile tensorflow (either with bazel or with cmake) I get a libtensorflow.so and libtensorflow_framework.so that export their symbols without the usage of c++11, e.g.

`tensorflow::Status:ToString() const`.

When I take the headers and try to implement them in my own, external software and when I either link against the libtensorflow or try to use the software with libtensorflow the linker/software complains about

`` undefined reference to `tensorflow::Status::ToString[abi:cxx11]() const ``.

Now I've tried several methods. I tried building libtensorflow with

`bazel build --cxxopt="-std=c++11" //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so tensorflow:libtensorflow_framework.so`

and

`bazel build --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1" //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so tensorflow:libtensorflow_framework.so`

but it does not seem to have any effect on the libraries, the exported symbols are still non C++11.

I have also tried to specify

`#define GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0`

in my external software, before including any standard headers, but the linker still complains about undefined references.

What am I doing wrong? Or is it possible that what I'm trying to do doesn't work at all? With cmake I have tried version 1.8 (it is the only one that compiles for me) and with bazel I have tried 1.10 and 1.11.

Comment: Can you not just upgrade your compiler? GCC 4.8 is ancient.

Comment: This would indeed be the easiest solutions but the systems I deploy to use GCC 4.8. The whole software that is running on them is built around that and changing the linux image/compiler would entail a lot of work that I'm not sure my colleagues are willing to do since it would require a lot of additional testing. Believe me, I wish I could use a newer compiler. I built tensorflow on a machine with GCC 5 and everything was fine. It just didn't run on the target system.

Comment: Tell your collegues that the compiler you use is no longer supported by the vendor, and also not by TensorFlow. Tell them the oldest version still supported is GCC7. Tell them that they will only waste more time until they have to upgrade eventually anyways. Running a business like this is ridiculous.

Comment: Are you using gcc-4.8 to build your external software as well?

Comment: @ypnos: I concur, GCC 4.8 is old though I'm not sure there is anything I can do about it. I'll try to bring this up with my team leader. Is it true, though, that it is not supported? On the [tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) it says that up until tensorflow 2.0 they ues 4.8. I am in favour of upgrading the compiler, too.

Comment: @StephenNewell: curiously our development system is using GCC 5 though GCC 4.8 is installed, too. I tried switching to GCC 4.8 but I ran into a different problem I cannot recall at the moment since I don't have access to that system right now.

Comment: If your dev environment is using gcc 5, why don't you build tensorflow with the same compiler?  There was an ABI break with gcc 5 (at minimum `std::string`), so link errors may be the least of your problems.

Comment: The system the software is used on, as well as the jenkins that is used to build the packages, use GCC 4.8. When I didn't know that I had built tensorflow with GCC 5 and it worked without problems but it didn't run on the target systems so that, unfortunately, is not an option.